# Nodejs, MongoDB asynchronous callback problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm the beginner of nodejs and MongoDB.I tried to design RESTAPI but there was a problem.

Here is my router code.

```
app.post('/fcm',function(req,res){

    var beaconid = req.body.beacon_id;
    var my_token_id = req.body.user_id;

    User.find({beacon_id: beaconid}, function(err, output){
        if(err) return res.status(500).json({error: err});
        if(!output) return res.status(404).json({error: 'user not found in User collections.'});

        console.log("output user id :"+output.user_id + " beacon: " +output.beacon_id );
        target_token_id = output.user_id;
        res.json(output);
    });                
});
```

And this is user schema.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
user_id: String,
beacon_id: String
```

});

The result of above function in the console is:
output user id: undefined , beacon: undefined.

But json from res function is printed properly.

This codes look like very simple but I don't know what is the problem.
Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `find`, you are expecting 1 document **or more**. This means that the method `<Model>.find()` should logically return an array. You can make sure that is what happens by logging the `output` just after the query to make sure it is an array of documents.

To solve your problem, you can either access the document at index 0 of the array:

```
User.find({beacon_id: beaconid}, function(err, output){
    if(err) return res.status(500).json({error: err});
    if(!output) return res.status(404).json({error: 'user not found in User collections.'});

    console.log("output user id :"+output[0].user_id + " beacon: " +output[0].beacon_id );
    target_token_id = output[0].user_id;
    res.json(output);
});
```

Or use `findOne()` instead, that returns only one document.

```
User.findOne({beacon_id: beaconid}, function(err, output){
    if(err) return res.status(500).json({error: err});
    if(!output) return res.status(404).json({error: 'user not found in User collections.'});

    console.log("output user id :"+output.user_id + " beacon: " +output.beacon_id );
    target_token_id = output.user_id;
    res.json(output);
});
```

Comment: Wow.. It worked!!
In my another code, output.user_id + output.beacon_id was printed well.
So I did the same.
But now, as you said, my another code used findOne function..
Thank you. Your answer is really helpful to me.

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept/upvote the answer for other people if you found it useful.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Thank you.